# Upload MIT-licensed code to maven repository

Tags: licensing, mit-license, maven

I found some java source code under MIT license on Github, but it is not included in any maven repository. I asked in issue to publish it somewhere, but nobody answered and looks like this repo is not supported actively (contrubutors may not answer for few months).
Can I publish this project to maven repo by myself without permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MIT license itself (relevant parts bolded):

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, **publish**, **distribute**, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, **subject to the following conditions**:
>
> **The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software**

So yes, you can as long as the license is intact.